# CSS + Django - Displaying list of items with grid?

Tags: html, css, django

I am trying to display a list of questions (think Stack Overflow's question list), and using grid to display them.  I want to display all the questions in the `content` section and have a separate `sidebar` section for other stuff.  The web page will basically [look like this](https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/9497/2-col-layout-left.png); A=content, B1=sidebar.

The thing is, I can't figure out how I can repeat a list of questions in the `content` section without also repeating content in the `sidebar` section.  My `content` section is itself a grid.

What should I do?

---

**This doesn't work, because the `content` class repeats**

```
<div class="body">

    {% for question in questions %}
    <div class="content">
        <div class="content1">
            ... content here
        </div>
        <div class="content2">
            ... content here
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}

    <div class="sidebar">
        ... content here
    </div>

</div>
```

---

**This works, but it is not optimal because the `sidebar` section repeats as well**

```
{% for question in questions %}
<div class="body">

    <div class="content">
        <div class="content1">
            ... content here
        </div>
        <div class="content2">
            ... content here
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="sidebar">
        ... content here
    </div>

</div>
{% endfor %}
```

---

**CSS**

```
.body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
}

.content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 40px 500px 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are including body tag also you need to omit that one try like this

```html
<div class="body">
    {% for question in questions %}
    <div class="content">
        <div class="content1">
            ... content here
        </div>
        <div class="content2">
            ... content here
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="sidebar">
        ... content here
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: With this setup, the `sidebar` section repeats as well.  I do not want the `sidebar` section to repeat.  I only want the `content` section to be repeated.

Answer (score 0):

If I get what you want is contents in `content` div to repeat

```
<div class="body">

<div class="content">
   {% for question in questions %}
    <div class="content{{ forloop.counter }}"> <-- for incrementing number from 1 to n(number of objects). 
        ... content here
    </div>
   {% endfor %}
</div>

<div class="sidebar">
    ... content here
</div>
```